# What is the maven repository of spring-boot 1.4.0 SNAPSHOT OR is there any alternative way to use 1.4.0 SNAPSHOT in our maven project?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies, snapshot

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ showing a `beta` version `spring-boot 1.4.0` SNAPSHOT. I want to use this version in my maven project. Maven does not resolve its dependency I have tried this

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Please let me know how I can use `spring-boot 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` version in my maven project. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use this version of spring boot we need to replace the parent tag in POM.xml file with following:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And add following repository tag just below the parent tag. On re-importing dependencies the dependency will be automatically resolved.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```